# Testing if URL does not contain set

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

```
 if(/\/?p(\d+)$/.test(window.location.pathname)) {
      } else {
        if(hrefArray.length > 1) {
     postLast.html('<center><img  class="loadingImg" src="'+imgUrl+'"/></center>');
     infiniteScroll();
       }
   }
```

I know there are some elements that are arrays in the code, but my question is instead of doing

```
 if() {

  } else {
      //run code here
  }
```

I was wondering how I would test the url if it did NOT contain p19 `/\/?p(\d+)$/` do I do

```
 var regex=(/\/?p(\d+)$/);
 if(!regex.test(window.location.pathname) {}
```

I am curious on this, I know how to test if element is defined and so forth, just not sure on it with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex.test` returns a boolean.  The `.` (object resolution operator) in JavaScript has higher precedence than `!` (the not operator) excepting parentheses.

That is to say that in

```
! /(?:)/.test("")
```

The `.` occurs before the `!`, which reverses its value.

You can check that `p19` (or `p` followed by at least one digit) is *not* in the string with

```
!/p\d+$/.test(window.location.pathname)
```

The other parts you have in the regex are not useful.

Comment: What does $ mean again? as I've tested these regex codes to see the boolean value on one of the pages contain p15 and they kept coming up as false (Without the !) and then I took out the $ and it says true like it should

Comment: `$` means the end of the string

Comment: Oh ok lol no wonder why it wasn't working. It's in the middle of the string not at end